# Wordpress Javascript collisions, how to debug?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

My blog is having trouble running the Disqus plugin and also seemingly any javascript I put within the sidebar widget. It is apparently my theme that is causing this (Since these plugins actually work in another theme) but I am having trouble debugging... i have tried to disable all plugins as well to no avail.

Firebug returns as "Failed to load resource" for the javascript url I tried to put, and even won't print anything with docment.write or alert.

site is http://www.leonfresh.com/blog

Any idea how to debug or solutions would be very much appreciated Thanks!

UPDATE 1

Turns out I have a script { display: none } in the code! it's a user defined stylesheet it says and I have no idea where to look for this...
https://i.stack.imgur.com/91iC6.png

Comment: I'd look in the error console too. Sometimes, variables are reassigned, functions redeclared, and multiple implementations of jQuery (and other libraries) throwing each other off. With plugins in CMS, I've seen the last of those more often that I expected...

Comment: Yes  I have tried that and the error is within the error console. By the way the javascript works in iphone, strangely. . . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Wow, funny but I think this actually is the solution. I found a [related thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/disqus-dev/UXoRYju9lYY/IftgI77EU1AJ) in Google Groups. You can use that as an alternative, but the problem is Disqus is expecting the  and because of your malformed HTML, it's null instead.*

(Original:) Probably unrelated, but your disqus  container is inside some other malformed HTML:

`<div id="content-wrap-footer" style="margin: 0 0 60px; width: 900px;></div>`

Note there is no closing `"` for `style=""`

Corrected as:

```
<div id="content-wrap-footer" style="margin: 0 0 60px; width: 900px;"></div>
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that fixed the disqus! but the javascript in the sidebar is still not working.  I'll be trying some w3 validator fixing the errors for now...

Comment: Welcome! I don't see any errors being thrown. Where is the code (what lines, or what file location?) that handles the sidebar?

Comment: Can you try: `<script type="text/javascript">` or simply `<script>` in place of what you have there now before document.write()?

Comment: I actually got the javascript to work now within the sidebar by trying code within the single.PHP file instead of adding it within widgets. But, the 2leep javascript widget is weird, it only works on iphone apparently but not on chrome, it shows that error failed to load resource on firebug.

Comment: The code for it is             <script language="javascript" src="http://2leep.com/ticker2/11028860/custom/1/6/160/bottom/transparent|0|Georgia,Georgia,serif|1.4em|0.04em|12px|180px|7005|0|1px|%23c0c0c0|center|middle|square|0||black">
            </script>